# How to hold the first parameter and print it depending whether the other parameter is satisfied or not?

Tags: bash, shell

I got a scripting question. I have a shell command that produces the output below. Please note there's only one but in reality there are many results.

```
NAME   | xpr          : SEVERITY
       | xxpr         : 000
       | clavv        :
       | clfic        :
       | name         :
       | domain       : V
       | azzl         : U_
       | utt          : WFH
       | info         :
       | sev          : 0005
```

So, my goal is to grep on the line of the NAME to get its actual name which is SEVERITY. But, I would only like to print it if the line "sev" has 0005. If not, do not print the name. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are there always 10 lines between `NAME` and `sev`? That would make things very simple.

Comment: Is sev a mandatory element? Does the section end with the start of the next Name in col 1?

Answer (score 2):

The following command works under the assumption that there are always ten lines between `NAME` and the `sev` attribute.

```
yourCommand | grep -B10 -Ew 'sev *: *0005' | grep -Pow 'NAME *\| *xpr *: *\K.*'
```

The first part extracts ten-line-blocks ending with `sev : 0005`. The second part extracts the names from these blocks (`SEVERITY` in your example).

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm checking if it works or not. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @JoieTamayo did it work? If so, I would be happy if you could accept this answer. If not, your feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in Bash :

```
[[ ! -z " $( grep -E 'sev *: *0005' test.txt ) "   ]] && grep -E '^NAME' test.txt | awk -F':' '{ print $2}'
```

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

If distance between 'NAME' and 'sev' is not fixed you must to grep twice

```
a=$(yours_shell_command); echo "$a" | grep -q 'sev *: 0005' && echo "$a" | grep 'NAME' | sed 's/.*: //'
```